# missing parent and children in AsyncResult/GroupResult

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

**Setup:**
python 3.7.3, 
celery 4.3.0,
RabbitMQ 3.7.16,
Redis 5.0.4

I'm trying to build an app that shows canvas flows.
I'm using rabbitMQ as broker and Redis as backend.

Consider the following canvas flow:

```
cf = add.si(0, 0) | group(add.si(1, 1), add.si(2, 2)) | add.si(3, 3)
res = c1.apply_async()
```

Running in debug mode and inspecting `res`, everything looks fine:
res is `AsyncResult` instance of the last task `add.si(3, 3)`, it has no children and its parent is `GroupResult` instance.

Looking in the `GroupResult` children also looks fine, I can see that it has two children - `group(add.si(1, 1)` and `add.si(2, 2)` and its parent is `AsyncResult` instance `add.si(0, 0)`.

Now I expected to see the same behavior when I tried to get the `AsyncResult` object by task_id:

```
task_info = AsyncResult(<uuid of task add.si(3, 3)>, app=app)
```

Now I see that `task_info.parent` is None.
Why is that?

Looking farther in Flower I can see the `task add.si(3, 3)` parent_id is `add.si(0, 0)` uuid - why is that?

I tried to implement the events loop listener (similar to Flower) and I don't see the `GroupResult` task. Is there a way to see it?
Is it a bug? is it hidden by design? I see in Flower's logs that there's a `celery.group` task. Is there a way to expose it?

```
[I 191107 19:48:36 command:147] Registered tasks:
    ['celery.accumulate',
      'celery.backend_cleanup',
      'celery.chain',
      'celery.chord',
      'celery.chord_unlock',
      'celery.chunks',
      'celery.group',
      'celery.map',
      'celery.starmap']
```

Here is my code:

```
import time
from celery import Celery, group
from celery.result import AsyncResult, GroupResult


def get_app():
    return Celery(
        'worker',
        broker='pyamqp://localhost/vhost',
        backend='redis://localhost/0'
    )


app = get_app()


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x + y


cf = add.si(0, 0) | group(add.si(1, 1), add.si(2, 2)) | add.si(3, 3)
res = cf.apply_async()

time.sleep(5)  # just in case - wait for the tasks to finish

print(type(res.parent))             # <class 'celery.result.GroupResult'>
print(len(res.parent.children))     # 2
print(type(res.parent.parent))      # <class 'celery.result.AsyncResult'>
print(res.parent.parent.result)     # 0


same_res = AsyncResult(res.id, app=app)
print(type(same_res.parent))             # <class 'NoneType'>
# print(len(same_res.parent.children))     # 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'
# print(type(same_res.parent.parent))      # 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'
# print(same_res.parent.parent.result)     # 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'


same_group_res = GroupResult(res.parent.id, app=app)
print(same_group_res.parent)    # None
print(same_group_res.children)  # None
```

I opened issue [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5824).

Comment: It is by any chance an open-source app? A good Celery workflow (canvas) viewer is a really good thing to have.

Comment: yea @DejanLekic, that's the plan